# Java is not giving output, sum between two integers

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I was trying to make the following program:

The user gives two integers as an input (first and last). The program is supposed to give the sum between those two numbers, but when I run the program I don't get an output. However, when I put for the first input a bigger integer than the last input, I get the first input as result. This is my code:

```
public class TheSumBetweenTwoNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("First: ");
        int first = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Last: ");
        int last = Integer.parseInt(reader.nextLine());

        int sum = 0;

        while (first <= last); {
            sum += first;
            first++;
        }

        System.out.println("The sum is: " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: There should not be a semicolon following the `while` condition; it acts as the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: close due to "simple typographical error", thx @rgettman

Comment: Did you try to debug to find the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your while loop runs without making a change to the block that it contains. you have closed the while loop before it even enters the block.

```
while (first <= last) {
            sum += first;
            first++;
        }
```

try this

Comment: Thanks! I figured out I put a ';' in by mistake.